# How to get data in sematic model in power bi premium from SSAS?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I deployed sematic model in power bi premium from SSAS tabular. how can I get data in that model?
Looking for any suggestions please......

we created premium worksace. I copied solution file to client environment and using through tabular editor we deployed in power bi premium .